# Do I need to recreate CK.pem when I renew the SSL certificate for ios push notification?

Tags: xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I renew the SSL certificate for ios push notification provider do I need to recreate  CK.pem and repeat all steps in keychan and terminal and then upload these certificate with CK.pem to my server ? or just I need to upload the renewal development.cer & production.cer to my server and replace the old one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to replace all the old certificates with new one.I have tried in one my app and it works fine after replacing the certificates wherever i used.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: do you mean if I need to replace all certificates even the CK.pem or I can use old CK.pem and replace the other certificates only

Comment: You need to replace all @user1288377